# Issues utilizing return value from out stream external process

Tags: groovy, process, stream

I have been banging my head on the keyboard long enough and succumb to ask for help on this matter. I am trying to execute a process in a groovy script that would run on a Linux box. So far I am able to receive a return of a number.

```
    def proc1 = 'grep -o -i ERROR| analysis.tmp'.execute()
    def proc2 = 'wc -l'.execute()
    proc1 | proc2
    proc2.waitFor()
```

This allows me to see the number of instances on that *.tmp file.
The variable below return a number as expected, fine so far.

```
${proc2.text}
>3818
```

The issue becomes when trying to create an if statement, the variable as it stands has a format that I am not able to operate comparisons with.

What have I tried?
Tried to place this value into an integer variable - failed
Tried to place this value into another String, and then modify it to an integer - that also failed.
I am just running out of google searches for the solution.

Comment: Please add the code, that is failing, to the question and also the errors you see or the unexpected behaviour.